# Attempt at proof of differential version of Grönwall's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have quickly thought up a proof for the following inequality but I am not sure if it is correct, so hopefully someone can catch a mistake if I have made one.

So if we have positive constants C and K, and a $C^1$ function $u(t): [0,a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$u(t) \leq C + K \int_0^t u(s) ds$$

then I have to show $u(t) \leq Ce^{Kt}$ for all $t \in [0,a]$

heres what I have:

Since K is a positive constant

$u(t) \leq Ku(t)$.

Now, differentiating both sides of the given inequality gives that $u'(t) \leq K u(t)$, and so the worst case is that equality holds, in which case we have

$u'(t) = Ku(t)$

for which we know the general solution is $u(t) = u(0)e^{Kt}$. Using this fact we get that $u(t) \leq u(0) e^{Kt}$, and plugging in $t=0$ into the given inequality gives

$u(0) = C \implies u(t) \leq C e^{Kt}$

as desired.

Comment: A few comments. First, $u(t) \leq Ku(t)$ obviously assumes $K \geq 1$. Second, you cannot differentiate on both side of an inequality, take for example, $x \leq 1$, on $[0,1]$, but then $1 \leq 0$ is obviously wrong.

Comment: Thank you, your comments are absolutely right, I will start thinking of another approach